# How to order result according to another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, inner-join, where-clause

I want to select products in order to best selling items according to another table.

```
select product_id
       from wp_product_details_fields
       where field in ( 'brand', 'model')
       group by product_id
       having  (  max(`field` = 'brand' and `value` = 'Intel') = 1 
                  OR
                  max(`field` = 'model' and `value` = 'Core i7') = 1  ) 
       order by (SELECT COUNT(*) AS magnitude 
                        FROM wp_order_items 
                        GROUP BY product_id 
                        ORDER BY magnitude DESC)
```

I've got this Error:

> MySQL said: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: You can only have 1 row in the subquerry. And it would be good to see your tables stucture as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM (your complex query w/o ORDER BY) wpd
Left JOIN wp_order_items USING (product_id)
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) /* DESC */
```

Comment: I simplified the query to get to the point, but my original query was something I just edited. Please check again

Comment: Thank you, The only thing is that this query only sorts the products that are in the wp_order_items table. I'm just trying to sort in order to best selling items, not remove them. How can I fetch rows even now exists in wp_order_items table?

Comment: I found that I should use left Join, thanks for your help.